# Change Width of Border CSS

Tags: css, list, rss, border

I'd like to know how to change the width of the border of this list (an RSS feed) so that it's around half the content's width and centred, without changing the width of the DIV or the RSS feed.

```
.rssBody ul { list-style: none; 
}

.rssRow,.rssRow p { 
    margin-bottom:-5px;
    border-top:1px dashed #000000;

}
```

This is the RSS feed's CSS:

```
#recent_feed{
    top:213px;
    right:23px;
    width:230px;
    padding-bottom:80px;
    font-family:'MuseoSlab', 'Helvetica', 'Arial';
    font-size:16px;
    text-align:justify;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://www.cjfoote.co.uk/news/index.html

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention - I've tried "border-width-top", and that doesn't work since it simply changes the width of the dashes in the border, not the total width. I don't want to change the border's appearance, just how wide it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using a psuedo-element, though this isn't necessarily friendly across all browsers. Should be [IE 8+](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3abefore).

```
.rssRow:before, .rssRow p:before {
    content: ""; /* So that it will show */
    display: block; /* So it can have width */
    width: 50%; /* Make sure position on these elements is relative (or something besides default) */
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
    margin: 0px auto; /* Center the line */
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works great! The only problem is that the border isn't centred now. I've tried "padding-left:30px;" etc. but it doesn't move. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put that in the code. Do `margin: 0px auto;` on it to center.

Comment: Margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; works too, but your way is neater. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisFoote No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as best (if it solves your problem) by using the check at the right hand side.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing - at the moment, the list elements (the recent news "headlines") are spaced 25px apart from the dashed border. I can't figure out how to move them closer together (so that they're 15px apart top and bottom). I think the solution's probably something like adding a negative padding-top value, but since padding values can't be negative, I'm not sure what to use. Any ideas?

Comment: Currently, your list elements are in `<h4>`, which by default have a margin around them. If you set a different value you for those tags, you'll change the distance to the lines.

Answer (score 2):

CSS borders are applied to the full dimensions of an element, and can't be applied to only a certain portion or by a certain width or height. It will always border the entire element.

To accomplish something similar, your best option is to create an image that looks like the border effect you are trying to accomplish, and set that as the elements background.

Comment: - or another div narrower and floating in just the right position behind the first